# how to transform/stretch/shear a plot in maple with plot3d

Tags: maple, plot3d

here is my question.

> ```
> test:=v^3;
> plot3d(test,u=0..1-v, v=0..1);
> ```

How can I  transform this plot in the right triangle into an equilateral triangle?
So that the three edges of the plot are the same length.
I wanna, squish it, or shear?
any tools i can use? Or can I do it using some tricks to change the function?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro6Iw.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
P := plot3d(v^3,u=0..1-v, v=0..1):

plottools:-transform((x,y,z)->[x+y/2,y*sqrt(3)/2,z])(P)
```

Seen with `orientation=[-90,0,0]` the first of those could be,

[image]

and the transformed result,

[image]